# c bitfields strange behaviour with long int in struct

Tags: c++, c, struct, bit-fields

i am observing strange behaviour when i run the following code.
i create a bitfield by using a struct, where i want to use 52 bits, so i use long int.
The size of long int is 64 bits on my system, i check it inside the code.
Somehow when i try to set one bit, it alwas sets two bits. one of them is the one i wanted to set and the second one is the index of the first one plus 32. 
Cann anybody tell me, why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct foo {
  long int x:52;
  long int:12;
};

int main(){
  struct foo test;
  int index=0;
  printf("%ld\n",sizeof(test));
  while(index<64){
    if(test.x & (1<<index))
      printf("%i\n",index);
    index++;
  }
  test.x=1;
  index=0;
  while(index<64){
    if(test.x & (1<<index))
      printf("%i\n",index);
    index++;
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Sry forgot to post the output, so my question was basicly not understandable...
The Output it gives me is the following:

8

0

32

Comment: The code you've posted has undefined behavior.  (You access `test.x` before initializing it.)  So anything can happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`index` is of type `int`, which is probably 32 bits on your system. Shifting a value by an amount greater than or equal to the number of bits in its type has undefined behavior.

Change `index` to `unsigned long` (bit-shifting signed types is ill-advised). Or you can change `1<<index` to `1L << index`, or even `1LL << index`.

As others have pointed out, `test` is uninitialized. You can initialize it to all zeros like this:

```
 struct foo test = { 0 };
```

The correct `printf` format for `size_t` is `%zu`, not `%ld`.

And it wouldn't be a bad idea to modify your code so it doesn't depend on the non-portable assumption that `long` is 64 bits. It can be as narrow as 32 bits. Consider using the `uint_N_t` types defined in `<stdint.h>`.

I should also mention that bit fields of types other than `int`, `unsigned int`, `signed int`, and `_Bool` (or `bool`) are implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks alot, this respond was realy informative and solved my problem entirely, i will also use your advisis!

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior in your code, as you check the bits in `text.x` without initializing the structure. Because you don't initialize the variable, it will contain random data.

Comment: True, but that's probably not the cause of the symptoms he's seeing.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well, it's undefined behavior, so there's really no way to tell... ;)

Comment: True in principle, but if we assume that `test` happens to be all zero bits initially, and that `int` is 32 bits, then the *other* undefined behavior of `1 << index` explains the behavior he's seeing.